# How to make popup registration using bootstrap modals in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I spent a lot of time trying to make this using Devise gem, but decided to do it anoter way - writing my own controllers.

I want that, modal didn't hide if there errors in  registration or login.

I think I should render js so need to use Ajax, that I don't know.

My simple controllers(I need edit them, there is error there):

```
   def new
    @user = User.new
   end

   def create
     @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
   else
  render :js => "('#sign_up').modal('show');"//or something else I don't know
   end
  end
```

And code in my application.html.erb (where should I put it in new.js.erb?):

```
  <%= link_to  "Sign_up", '#sign_up', { 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => "#sign_up"}%>

    <div id="sign_up" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
   <%= render :template => "users/new" %>
  </div>
```

I receive error:

```
    undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
      3: <div class="row">
      4:   <div class="span6 offset3">
      5:     <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
.....
```

**EDITED:**

When I put @user in home controller(my root_path)

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController 
    def home
      @user = User.new 
    end    
 end
```

it all worked, but is it good?
I want to stay on page, where I clicke sign up. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used modal in a similar manner I have rendered the page on my modal and it works for me  with the validations

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="myclass">Enquiry</a>
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
             <h3>Enquiry form</h3>
        </div>
        <%=render :template => "users/new"%> 
    </div>
```

Comment: you put it in application.html.erb?

Comment: Strange,that in anoter projects the same things worked...Still getting the same error

Comment: You can put it in your views and it should work.It works fine for me.

Comment: I will edit question and you will check if we inderstanded each other

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but i would assume that this is very important to what you are trying to do.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app